# How do I set a maximum column width?

Tags: tables, varwidth

My problem is that I have many tables in my document with the same layout, and I want to specify the maximum width of a specific column to be 5 cm. I tried with p{5cm} but it make the column fix 5 cm wide and it looks odd with only a short word in it. I want it to be as narrow as possible, and split it into two lines, if it's wider than 5 cm. Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: I changed your title to reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: I reworded a sentence from your question to make it a little clearer. Feel free to revert if you prefer the previous version.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it with `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type
\usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{4cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column

Table with short rows:

\begin{tabular}{|M|}
hello hello hello
\end{tabular}

Same table, with long row:

\begin{tabular}{|M|}
hello hello hello hello hello hello 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to:

[image]

Thank-you for inspiring me to look for this answer. It is a nice question!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! And thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I'm really surprised that there isn't any of the tabular packages that supports maximum width columns out of the box.

Comment: Fails with multiple lines and cols. gives: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. e.g.
\begin{tabular}{MM}
hello hello hellohello& hello hellohello hello hello\\
hello hello hello hello hello hellohello hello& hellohello hello hello
hello &hello hello\\
\end{tabular}

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the column type `V` of `varwidth`. The output is slightly different from the ouput of Yossi Farjoun (see that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385057/vertical-padding-for-multiline-cells-using-varwidth/616711#616711)).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{varwidth} % must be loaded after array

\begin{document}

Table with short rows:

\begin{tabular}{|V{4cm}|}
hello hello hello
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
Same table, with long row:

\begin{tabular}{|V{4cm}|}
hello hello hello hello hello hello 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type

\begin{document}

Table with short rows:

\begin{tabular}{|p{4in}|}
hello hello hello
\end{tabular}

Same table, with long row:

\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|}
hello hello hello hello hello hello 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. You specify a _fixed_ column width, not a _maximal_ one.