# Error while defining custom tabular column width

Tags: tables, macros

I am trying to define the maximum width of a tabular column, see the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{float}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{booktabs}
\usepackage[]{array}
\usepackage[]{varwidth}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\newcolumntype{\vbf}{>{\begin{varwidth}{3.0cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}

        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf}
            \toprule
             0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            \midrule
             1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
             2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45 \\
             3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85 \\
             4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ^^@-\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.21            \midrule
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is there same special reason to use `varwidth`? From your MWE I can conclude, that you actually need `S` column type from package `siunitx`.

Comment: I found this as an example. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4709/how-do-i-set-a-maximum-column-width

Comment: If you set one single cell as `\begin{varwidth}{3cm}7121855.55\end{varwidth}` there is nothing happening IMO. What do you try to get here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is caused by missing `\arraybackslash` in your definition of column. I also sugest to not name column type with macro like `\vbf`, better is select for example some leter as has been used in answer which you like to repit. SO:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[]{float}
    \usepackage[]{booktabs}
    \usepackage[]{array}
    \usepackage[]{varwidth}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{4cm}\arraybackslash}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{M}}
\toprule
 0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\midrule
 1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
 2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45  \\
 3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85  \\
 4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It works as you expected. Tested!

Comment: Since you mentioned `siunitx` in comments, it would be a nice addition showing the different (and better) way.

Comment: I also would like to have line breakes.

Comment: @egreg, you already do this! In my answer I was focused only to OP problem . By the way, from your solution with `\tabularnewline` I learn something new!

Answer (score 3):

The example you found suggests `varwidth` for a very different situation, where line breaks in a cell are wanted. In your table you have nothing of that kind, so the output is exactly the same as if you just use `l`.

Here's the code that proves the claim, using `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` for ending lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{booktabs}
\usepackage[]{array}
\usepackage[]{varwidth}

\newcolumntype{\vbf}{>{\begin{varwidth}{3.0cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf\vbf}
\toprule
0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\midrule
1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \tabularnewline
2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45 \tabularnewline
3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85 \tabularnewline
4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l}
\toprule
0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\midrule
1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45 \\
3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85 \\
4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a different way to input the table, using `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\centering
\sisetup{group-digits=false}

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=8.2]
  S[table-format=8.2]
  S[table-format=6.2]
  S[table-format=7.2]
  S[table-format=7.2]
}
\toprule
0 & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} \\
\midrule
1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45 \\
3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85 \\
4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the column type `V` defined by `varwidth`, you have directly the expected output.

However, in your case, as said in other answers, it's probably better to use the columns `S` of `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{varwidth}% must be loaded after array

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{V{3cm}V{3cm}V{3cm}V{3cm}V{3cm}V{3cm}}
\toprule
 0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\midrule
 1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
 2 & 9992538.31 & 10211855.55 &  331381.44 & 6444971.54 & 6403637.45 \\
 3 & 9989460.45 & 10174367.75 &  282403.66 & 7065539.95 & 7152965.85 \\
 4 & 11773342.70 & 10413039.41 &  297383.17 & 6267637.00 & 6375493.07 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]