# Vertical padding for multiline cells using varwidth

Tags: tables, varwidth

To set a maximum column width, I use `varwidth` as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4712/71109). However, the vertical padding is only correct for single line cells, and is too little for multiline ones. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{1cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|M|c|}
    \hline
     asdf      & \\ \hline
     asdf asdf & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This results is:

[image]

I tried to use `varwidth` inside the cells (instead of defining a new column type with the array package), but this yielded the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
     \begin{varwidth}{1cm}asdf     \end{varwidth} & \\ \hline
     \begin{varwidth}{1cm}asdf asdf\end{varwidth} & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I also tried adding `\par` or double newlines to the cells, but none of my attempts resulted in proper vertical padding. Adding manual `vspace`s also did not work.

Is there a way to guarantee the same vertical padding for both single and multiline cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `cellspace` package, which aims at ensuring a minimal vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells and (slightly) change  the definition of the `M` column type with the `S` prespecifier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{1cm}}Sl<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|M|c|}
    \hline
     asdf & \\ \hline
     asdf asdf & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked well with the rest of my document - which has `longtable`s, `tabularx`s with redefined `tabularxcolumn`, `raggedright` cells, etc.

Comment: Just beware: if you load `siunitx`, which defines an `S` column type, you'll have to replace `S` with `C`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{makecell}% added
\setcellgapes{5pt}   % added

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells    % added
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
     \begin{varwidth}{1cm}asdf     \end{varwidth} & \\ \hline
     \begin{varwidth}{1cm}asdf asdf\end{varwidth} & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

**note:** this solution -- using `\makegapedcells` -- not work with column type `m` nor enable coloring table using `colortbl` or `[table]{xcolor}` packages. but this not degrade usefulness of this solution a lot since use of them is rare.

benefits of its use is that you not need to care about adding `S` attribute to cells type nor specific of its use in combination of `S` column type from `siunitx` package (also rare happen, but it is good to know, that there instead of `S` you should use `C`, what can be again limitation in case of use `tabularx` ...  etc :) )

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works well with the minimal example, but has some issues with my full document. Chief among these is the incompatibility with cell colors: I added `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to the preamble and added `\cellcolor{green}` to the first cell, but it had no effect.

Comment: It also did not work with the `m` column of the `tabularx` package.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas, in your question is not mentioned, that you need `m`column type! it is well known, that macro `\makegapedcells` is not compatible with it, so in this case i would recommended solution with `cellspace` package as Bernard do.

Comment: I tried to make the MWE as compact as possible and did not think that cell color or the `m` column type makes a difference for cell padding. Sorry for this. Your answer is a quality one, and thank you for editing it to include the aforementioned limitations. Too bad I cannot accept both answers.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas, i extend my note with some further information :) maybe it can help you. happy tex-ing!

Answer (score 0):

When loaded after `array`, the package `varwidth` defines a new columntype called `V`. With that column type, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{varwidth}% must be loaded after array

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|V{1cm}|c|}
    \hline
     asdf      & \\ \hline
     asdf asdf & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]